# XAML menu + menuitems throw error for wasm-app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uno

I build an application which has to run as a web-assembly.

I use visual studio 2022 preview

In my shared projects xaml I have this code to define the menubar

```
 <Grid x:Name="Grid_Menu" Grid.Row="1">
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="TEAM">
            <MenuItem Header="Mitarbeiter"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Qualitätsmanagement"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Admin"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
 </Grid>
```

Compiling gives me this error message

```
CS0246  Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Menu" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).
```

Sorry i only got the german language pack, but it translates to type or namespace "Menu" not found (missing using-directive or assemblyreference).

What do I need to do to get the menubar running in wasm?

Answer (score 0):

More digging showed the answer. Since Uno converts UWP to wasm, some stuff used in WPF is not supported.
XAML != XAML it seems.

The XAML structure which works is

```
<MenuBar VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <MenuBarItem Title="TEAM">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Mitarbeiterübersicht">
            <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE902;"/>
            </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
        </MenuFlyoutItem>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Qualitätsmanagement">
            <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xEADF;"/>
            </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
        </MenuFlyoutItem>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Rechteverwaltung">
            <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE9E9;"/>
            </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
        </MenuFlyoutItem>
    </MenuBarItem>
</MenuBar>
```

Icons used are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font).

I wish the xaml preview would work better, but at least i can progress further :)